# TopicDisallowed Push Notification

Tags: ios, react-native, apn

I have a small issue. I am trying to test my push notification feature but I can't figure it out. I set up a webRTC page that I'm using to send the notification (I don't own 2 IOS devices). All the certificates/keys were generated using fastlane actions (match and pem). I am aware I'm using a production feature for the apnOptions and I generated the correct certificates. When I write some gibberish on the key or teamID, I get errors so that means my certificate should be alright. The bundle identifier is exactly the one that appears on the developer Apple page.`enter code here`

Here are my token and my notification:

```
 var apnProvider = new apn.Provider({
  token: {
    key: "cert/key.p8",
    keyId: "#",
    teamId: "#"
  },
  production: true
  });


if (deviceToken) {
        if (platform === 'ios') {
          let note = new apn.Notification()
          note.alert = 'Hello World'
          note = Object.assign(note, {
            // Expires 1 hour from now.
            expiry: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
            badge: 3,
            payload: payloadBody,
            topic: "org.#.#"
          })

          apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then((result) => {
            console.log('APNPROVIDER RESULT', `PLATFORM: ${platform}, RESULT:${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
          })
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Did you enabled the push notifications from capabilities under target in your project?

Comment: Yes, I did enable it.

Answer (score 5):

I found out in the end. It turned out that if I use a voip bundle I need to add at the end of the bundle .voip. So, a bundle would look something like org.test.Test.voip. I'm done..

Comment: Thanku so much. You have saved my life. where did this .voip info is written?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was, Server was taking push kit device token i.e. voIP token, and the bundle id was "com.something".

**Solution:** For voIP type of notifications user, "com.something.voip" topic/bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

IOS follows proper format for push notification. If you do not follow proper format your notifications won't be delivered. There should be a `aps` tag also.

```
{
  "aps": {
     "alert": "Hello World",
     "sound": "default"
   },
  "customData": {
    "CustomKey": "CustomValue",
    }
 }
```

You can follow this link for reference 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Answer (score 0):

Double check the *Topic Name*, I've encountered this problem with a *typo* in the Topic Name.

Answer (score 0):

please check your topic usuually it happens when you entered wrong app bundle id

```
topic: "add correct bundle id"
```

check below link as well
https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn#sending-a-notification